# Office 365 API EWS calendar not expanding recurring events

Tags: api, rest, calendar, office365, recurring

I am using REST services with the new Office 365 API Preview.

The following request returns the "Non-recurring appointments and recurring master appointments", but all "single occurrences of recurring series" are missing:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Events?$top=30&$select=Subject,Start,End&$filter=End+ge+2014-12-01T01%3A00%3A00Z+and+Start+le+2015-02-01T01%3A00%3A00Z
```

The EWS Managed API has a method `ExchangeService.FindAppointments` that expands a series of recurring calendar items and returns "Non-recurring appointments, single occurrences of recurring series, and exceptions to recurring series". [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn727655(v=exchg.150).aspx#sectionSection2)

What parameters do I need to use to also get the "single occurrences of recurring series, and exceptions to recurring series" using the Office 365 REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your interest in Office 365 Calendar APIs!  We are currently rolling out an API to expand a specific meeting series for a given timeframe, and an API to provide a calendar view i.e. list of all meetings (single instances, occurrences and exceptions of a meeting series) for a given timeframe.  As soon as the deployment is complete, we will update our docs with details on the new APIs.  I believe one of these APIs will meet your needs.

Can you please try the following URL?  This new CalendarView API is almost fully deployed, but we are still updating documentation.  In the meantime, please let me know if this request works for you.

```
https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/CalendarView?$top=30&$select=Subject,Start,End&startDateTime=2014-12-01T01:00:00Z&endDateTime=2015-02-01T01:00:00Z
```

Let me know if you have any questions or need more info.

Thanks,

Venkat

Comment: Venkat, I would like to know if it's possible to combine between fetching all events (include recurring events), and fetching only events that changed from DateTimeLastUpdated in once call. Thanks.